# How do I compile a C/C++ program through windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, gcc, console, compilation, mingw

Im new to the C/C++ programming language an so far have used the Code::blocks program for writing and compiling programs. However I need to know how to compile a program via windows command prompt as I need to access the assembly code created. My compilers are mingw32-gcc.exe, mingw32-g++.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Compile Programs with MinGW -- A Guide for New Users](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGWforFirstTimeUsers).
To make `gcc` produce assembler code, use `-S` option:

> ```
>    -S  Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.
>
>        By default, the assembler file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix .c, .i, etc., with .s.
>
>        Input files that don't require compilation are ignored.
> ```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, needed to set PATH for MinGW\bin in enviroment variables before commands would work.

Answer (score 3):

if you have codeblocks installed with mingw as the gcc compiler then follow these steps

1. Right click on my computer -> go to properties -> advance system settings
2. Then make an environment variable named **PATH** and paste the  complete url like program file (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin.
3. now open cmd
4. go to the directory where your program is saved.
5. type gcc program_name.c -o program_name.exe to compile the program.
6. run the program by typing program_name