# Vim: Compiling with gcc

Tags: c, windows, gcc, vim, compilation

I've been trying to find a solution for my problem for a while now.

I am trying to use gcc to compile my c programs on Windows 7.

My current code

```
set makeprg=gcc\ %\
```

gives me "gcc: error: missing filename after '-o'.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I think this link will help you ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281493/how-do-i-compile-a-c-c-program-through-windows-command-prompt

Comment: That's not related to my question what so ever...

Comment: Read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). There is an entire chapter about how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Comment: That still doesn't help me as it only explains how to use options. What I'm looking for is a way to be able to compile and execute c programs within vim using gcc.

Answer (score 1):

If your gnumake program is correctly configured (linux, cygwin, ...), but unfortunately not with mingw, you don't need to tweak `:makeprg` for mono-files pet project compiled where the source files are.

In those cases, if you need to add options, just set them into $CXXFLAGS, $LDFLAGS, $CFLAGS, $CC, $CXX, etc. from vim:

```
:let $CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -std=c++11'
```

Now, back to your problem (as I suspect the badly configured mingw), I'm not sure why you have a backslash at the end of your expression. I'd have used (a plugin, but this is a different story):

```
" in a c ftplugin/ or a local vimrc in the directory where C pet projects are
:setlocal makeprg=gcc\ %\ -o\ %<.exe
```